# What does <html> do in a grep command?

Tags: unix, grep

I was wondering what does the <> do in a grep command

- `grep a b c` , try to find `a` in file `b` and `c`
- `grep <html> foo`?

What does the `<>` do? Find the HTML tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When inside quotes...

```
grep '<html>' foo

grep "<html>" foo
```

...it does exactly that: find a `<html>` tag inside the `foo` file.

`grep` and `egrep` use POSIX regular expressions, which are described in the manual page of `regex`(7) – basic for `grep`, extended/modern for `egrep`. Neither version treats `<` or `>` specially.

---

When *not* inside quotes, however, it doesn't do anything useful.

```
grep <html> foo

grep < html > foo
```

Most commonly used shells will treat the above equally: run command `grep` with *no* arguments, reading from file named `html`, writing to file named `foo`. But this won't work, because there is no "pattern" to be given to `grep`, so you'll get an error message (and an empty `foo` file).

Comment: Since ricedragon is new to regular expressions, it is worth pointing out that `grep '<html>' foo` will not find `<html lang="en">`. It is often better to use an HTML parser for searching HTML.